# data = "SUCCESS" not triggering function

Tags: php, jquery

This function was working perfectly before and now does not, can anyone tell me why?

```
function addSelectedItem() {
        var saleItem = document.getElementById('selecteditem').value;
        var saleQty = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value);
        if (!saleQty || saleQty === 0) {
            alert('Please enter a quantity!');
            return;
        }
        $.post('../process/sale_addtobasket.php', {itemno: saleItem, itemqty: saleQty}, function(data) {
            if (data === 'SUCCESS') {
                $('#boxselecteditem').hide();
                $('#qty').val('');
                reloadReceipt();
            }
        });
    }
```

"../process/sale_addtobasket.php" responds with SUCCESS but the function does not trigger?

Comment: Show the response you got by post..

Comment: It responds with SUCCESS, that is it. Nothing else

Comment: probably your message contain spaces. So trim it before comparing since you are doing both data and type comparison of the response

Comment: ↑↑↑↑ `if ($.trim(data) === 'SUCCESS')` or remove in script `?>` or any character after that, even spaces, new lines, etc...

Comment: will check that, but it is really weird as it was working perfectly before.

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById('qty').value` instead of `$('#qty').val()` ?

Comment: @user3660291 Maybe an encoding or copy/paste issue?! Always encode script in utf8 without BOM (on windows)

Comment: To be honest I did not write this function, I am just trying to fix it

Comment: Ok, ($.trim(data) === 'SUCCESS') has worked for me. Thank you so much guys. Still very confused why it worked before and then stopped working ?????

Comment: I always used data.d to see the info returned, don't know if it applies here...

Comment: Probably some library you are including has trailing spaces after the closing ?> php tags (or less likely before the opening one). You can delete all closing ?> tags in PHP files to help avoid this.

Comment: Oh okay, I was under the impression it didn't matter. I will go through the program and do this